# WSO2 - ESB Pass through Proxy Post Request Failure

Tags: esb, wso2-esb

Hi guys can you help me out with my WSO2 - ESB problem.

I am experiencing the following error in our UAT environment but not in my SIT environment. I need a hint on why this is happening so I can change my CAR file or add the proper configuration to our server if needed.

For some reason when the Client doing a Post request I am experiencing a timeout error. Upon checking the logs I see that their is an error that states that the Payload could not be written as JSON. This does not happen in a GET request so I am at a lost. I can also confirm that the request is being sent in the back end using either GET/POST.

Please note that the following servers does not exist so app03/app04 so failure to connect to those server is expected (We only have 2 UAT servers but 4 in our PRD environment).

What I do not understand is why this only happens in Post request and if i need to modify my code or set something in the WSO2-ESB server.

For any clarification or additional information please do not hesitate to ask.

Thanks for your help

**Carbon Logs**

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-09-22 09:12:03,608]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  Request: Target URL = /services/XXXX-ws_PS/payments/validate, Client IP = 172.22.222.156, Request ID = urn:uuid:0df0d876-6093-4479-9537-70bbbdf4d649 {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-09-22 09:12:04,029]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  Response: To = /services/XXXX-ws_PS/payments/validate, IP = 172.22.222.156, RequestID = urn:uuid:0df0d876-6093-4479-9537-70bbbdf4d649 {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-09-22 09:12:04,029] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil} -  #writeAsJson. Payload could not be written as JSON. MessageID: urn:uuid:3b69a0e3-f6b3-4e49-8d14-23d7596c2366 {org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-09-22 09:12:04,029] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLSender} -  Failed to submit the response {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLSender}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Payload could not be written as JSON.
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.writeAsJson(JsonUtil.java:263)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter.writeTo(JsonStreamFormatter.java:61)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.submitResponse(PassThroughHttpSender.java:555)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:264)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:222)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:531)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:118)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:337)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:554)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:188)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-09-22 09:12:04,042] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender} -  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope> Unexpected error sending message back {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Failed to submit the response
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.handleException(PassThroughHttpSender.java:613)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:266)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:222)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:531)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:118)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:337)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:554)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:188)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Payload could not be written as JSON.
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.writeAsJson(JsonUtil.java:263)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter.writeTo(JsonStreamFormatter.java:61)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.submitResponse(PassThroughHttpSender.java:555)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:264)
    ... 16 more
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-09-22 09:12:04,047] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  Error: To = /services/XXXX-ws_PS/payments/validate, IP = 172.22.222.156, RequestID = urn:uuid:0df0d876-6093-4479-9537-70bbbdf4d649 {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-09-22 09:12:20,541]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  Request: Target URL = /services/XXXX-ws_PS/institutions/details/00239, Client IP = 172.22.222.156, Request ID = urn:uuid:e5aca458-03a6-41b3-81b5-d409c5eaa66a {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [-1] [] [2017-09-22 09:12:20,542]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ConnectCallback} -  Connection refused or failed for : app03.XXXX.uat.XXX.com.ph:50209 {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ConnectCallback}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-09-22 09:12:20,542]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext} -  Endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint with address https://app03.XXXX.uat.XXX.com.ph:50209/XXXX-ws/ will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-09-22 09:12:20,542]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext} -  Suspending endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint with address https://app03.XXXX.uat.XXX.com.ph:50209/XXXX-ws/ - last suspend duration was : 300000ms and current suspend duration is : 300000ms - Next retry after : Fri Sep 22 09:17:20 PHT 2017 {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-09-22 09:12:20,542]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.LoadbalanceEndpoint} -  Endpoint [XXXX-ws_LBEP] Detect a Failure in a child endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.LoadbalanceEndpoint}
TID: [-1] [] [2017-09-22 09:12:20,545]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ConnectCallback} -  Connection refused or failed for : app04.XXXX.uat.XXX.com.ph:50209 {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ConnectCallback}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-09-22 09:12:20,545]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext} -  Endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint with address https://app04.XXXX.uat.XXX.com.ph:50209/XXXX-ws/ will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-09-22 09:12:20,546]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext} -  Suspending endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint with address https://app04.XXXX.uat.XXX.com.ph:50209/XXXX-ws/ - last suspend duration was : 300000ms and current suspend duration is : 300000ms - Next retry after : Fri Sep 22 09:17:20 PHT 2017 {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-09-22 09:12:20,546]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.LoadbalanceEndpoint} -  Endpoint [XXXX-ws_LBEP] Detect a Failure in a child endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.LoadbalanceEndpoint}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-09-22 09:12:20,785]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  Response: To = /services/XXXX-ws_PS/institutions/details/00239, IP = 172.22.222.156, RequestID = urn:uuid:e5aca458-03a6-41b3-81b5-d409c5eaa66a {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [-1] [] [2017-09-22 09:15:03,802]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} -  Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-49847 Socket Timeout : 180000 Remote Address : h02610a24.ho.ad.XXX/172.22.222.156:58409 {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-09-22 09:30:09,430]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To: /, MessageID: urn:uuid:d233e911-f717-4d42-a24c-eca0e7c32768, Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [-1] [] [2017-09-22 09:47:24,248] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} -  I/O error: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler}
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at sun.security.ssl.EngineInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(EngineInputRecord.java:156)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:868)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doUnwrap(SSLIOSession.java:245)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:280)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:410)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:159)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:338)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:316)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:277)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-09-22 10:00:14,936]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To: /, MessageID: urn:uuid:d5e87ee5-d83b-4ded-8110-b64dd01ce08f, Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
```

**Proxy Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="XXXX-ws_PS" startOnLoad="true" transports="https http" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <property description="targetURL" expression="get-property('To')" name="targetURL" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property description="clientIP" expression="get-property('axis2','REMOTE_ADDR')" name="clientIP" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property description="requestID" expression="get-property('MessageID')" name="requestID" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <log description="requestLog" level="custom">
                <property expression="get-property('targetURL')" name="Request: Target URL"/>
                <property expression="get-property('clientIP')" name="Client IP"/>
                <property expression="get-property('requestID')" name="Request ID"/>
            </log>
            <send description="">
                <endpoint key="XXXX-ws_LBEP"/>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <log description="resposeLog" level="custom">
                <property expression="get-property('targetURL')" name="Response: To"/>
                <property expression="get-property('clientIP')" name="IP"/>
                <property expression="get-property('requestID')" name="RequestID"/>
            </log>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence>
            <log category="ERROR" description="errorLog" level="custom">
                <property expression="get-property('targetURL')" name="Error: To"/>
                <property expression="get-property('clientIP')" name="IP"/>
                <property expression="get-property('requestID')" name="RequestID"/>
            </log>
        </faultSequence>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

**Endpoint Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint name="XXXX-ws_LBEP" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <loadbalance algorithm="org.apache.synapse.endpoints.algorithms.RoundRobin">
        <endpoint>
            <http uri-template="https://app01.XXXX.uat.XXX.com.ph:50209/XXXX-ws/">
                <timeout>
                    <duration>600000</duration>
                    <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
                </timeout>
                <suspendOnFailure>
                    <initialDuration>300000</initialDuration>
                    <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
                    <maximumDuration>1800000</maximumDuration>
                </suspendOnFailure>
                <markForSuspension>
                    <retriesBeforeSuspension>3</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                    <retryDelay>30000</retryDelay>
                </markForSuspension>
            </http>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint>
            <http uri-template="https://app02.XXXX.uat.XXX.com.ph:50209/XXXX-ws/">
                <timeout>
                    <duration>600000</duration>
                    <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
                </timeout>
                <suspendOnFailure>
                    <initialDuration>300000</initialDuration>
                    <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
                    <maximumDuration>1800000</maximumDuration>
                </suspendOnFailure>
                <markForSuspension>
                    <retriesBeforeSuspension>3</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                    <retryDelay>30000</retryDelay>
                </markForSuspension>
            </http>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint>
            <http uri-template="https://app03.XXXX.uat.XXX.com.ph:50209/XXXX-ws/">
                <timeout>
                    <duration>600000</duration>
                    <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
                </timeout>
                <suspendOnFailure>
                    <initialDuration>300000</initialDuration>
                    <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
                    <maximumDuration>1800000</maximumDuration>
                </suspendOnFailure>
                <markForSuspension>
                    <retriesBeforeSuspension>3</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                    <retryDelay>30000</retryDelay>
                </markForSuspension>
            </http>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint>
            <http uri-template="https://app04.XXXX.uat.XXX.com.ph:50209/XXXX-ws/">
                <timeout>
                    <duration>600000</duration>
                    <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
                </timeout>
                <suspendOnFailure>
                    <initialDuration>300000</initialDuration>
                    <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
                    <maximumDuration>1800000</maximumDuration>
                </suspendOnFailure>
                <markForSuspension>
                    <retriesBeforeSuspension>3</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                    <retryDelay>30000</retryDelay>
                </markForSuspension>
            </http>
        </endpoint>
    </loadbalance>
</endpoint>
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of 'targetURL' is not correct. Instead define the endpoint in the  `<send>` So something like

```
<send>
  <endpoint key="XXXX-ws_LBEP" />
</send>
```

Comment: Sorry made a mistake in copying the code the ESB eclipse tool was still updating when I copied the code. Included it now but again the proper code is working in the SIT environment but somehow the POST request will not go through.